# How to target headings for a specific div ID?

Tags: css, stylesheet, html-heading

I am trying to style all the headings in my header with a different font-family than the headings on the rest of the page but I am having trouble getting the style to only apply to the specific header ID.

Here is what I tried:

```
#header h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
```

But this causes all h1/2/3/4 tags to use the Helvetica font regardless of if they are in the header div or not. I'm sure I am missing something simple, can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to add #header before each? Like #header h1, #header h2, etc.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you must do so:

```
#header h1,#header h2, #header h3, #header h4 {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to target all `hN` with the ID.

```
#header h1, 
#header h2, 
#header h3, 
#header h4 {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2drQ8/)