# Having issues with css margins and div image constraints, would love some advice or tips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margins

I'm trying to create a dynamic gallery and I keep running into an issue where the code appears correct in jsfiddle, but once I add it into wordpress I run into a number of issues. Mainly, the margins between the image titles and meta-data stretches to a ridiculous degree, and even though I'm pretty sure I'm using a workable div constraint, I must not be, because the last image breaks its container and messes up the line.

I think my issue may be partially due to the fact that I don't have a unique id to separate the gallery code from the built in styling of the WordPress theme I'm using, but I'm not entirely sure where to begin on that front. As for the rest, I honestly have no idea, I've searched "how to constrain/format/stretch/confine an image to a div container" and various other versions of the same question, but I still don't know where the issue is in my code.

Here's a link to my jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/nh2geqah/1/

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article,
aside,
details,
embed,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
nav,
ruby,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
#front-page-blog {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
}
#front-page-blog .featured-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#front-page-blog,
#front-page-blog .featured-image {
  background-color: white;
}
#front-page-blog::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#page {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#page {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(34, 34, 34, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(34, 34, 34, .3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
body,
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4545;
}
/* @media only screen and (min-width:1025px) */

body,
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-size: 1.37rem;
}
body {
  background-color: #444;
}
body,
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: #222;
}
html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
html {
  margin-top: 80px !important;
}
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0px;
  max-width: 1230px;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
}
.grid::after,
.row::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.twelve,
.eleven,
.ten,
.nine,
.eight,
.seven,
.six,
.five,
.four,
.three,
.two,
.one {
  width: 100%;
}
/* @media only screen and (min-width:800px) */

.three {
  width: 25%;
  width: -webkit-calc((100% / 12) * 3);
  width: calc((100% / 12) * 3);
}
#front-page-blog .three {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
/* @media only screen and (min-width:1025px) */

#front-page-blog .three,
#front-page-blog .grid-sizer {
  width: 25%;
}
/* @media only screen and (min-width:640px) */

#front-page-blog .gutter-sizer {
  width: 0px;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #222;
}
#front-page-blog a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#front-page-blog a {
  color: inherit;
}
#page > header a,
#page > section a,
#page > div a,
#page > footer a {
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
  -o-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
#front-page-blog .three > a {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: .1em;
}
#front-page-blog .three > a {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1);
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol,
dl,
address,
form,
fieldset {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
h1,
h1 a,
h2,
h2 a,
h3,
h3 a,
h4,
h4 a,
h5,
h5 a,
h6,
h6 a {
  clear: both;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.68em;
}
#front-page-blog .three .entry-title {
  /*.entry-title edits the picture caption font */
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#front-page-blog .three .entry-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#front-page-blog .three .entry-meta {
  /*.entry-meta edits the date font */
  font-size: 14px;
}
#front-page-blog .three .entry-meta {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#front-page-blog .three .entry-title,
#front-page-blog .three .entry-meta {
  display: block;
}
img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#front-page-blog .featured-image img {
  display: block;
}
#front-page-blog .three > a:hover {
  /*a:hover edits the effect of mousing over images */
  border-bottom-color: #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #222;
}
#front-page-blog .three > a:hover .featured-image {
  opacity: 0.9;
  /*Edits how faded gallery images turns as you mouse over them */
}
#front-page-blog .banner {
  /*Edits banner size, styling, and positioning */
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 32px;
  /*Edits 'Update' font size, no noticeable effect past 35px */
  margin-bottom: 1.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="js" lang="en">
<body class="home page page">
  <div class="hfeed site" id="page">
    <section id="front-page-blog">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelve column banner">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/updates/">Updates</a> 
          </div>
          <!-- .banner -->
        </div>
        <!-- .row -->
        <div class="row posts" style="height: 592.56px; position: relative;">
          <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
          <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
          <div class="three column post-1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/friends/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="12178071_484580551721878_1874327697_n" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/12178071_484580551721878_1874327697_n.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Friends</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                June 19, 2015
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-2" style="left: 300px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/work/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="ss-green-planting-on-deschutes-at-barden-propoerty-4-22-09-10-400x300" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/ss-green-planting-on-deschutes-at-barden-propoerty-4-22-09-10-400x300.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1"
                scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Work</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                July 19, 2015
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-3" style="left: 600px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/house/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="service-day-wss-green-at-bentley-farm-1-2009-016-17-400x300" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/service-day-wss-green-at-bentley-farm-1-2009-016-17-400x300.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1"
                scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">House</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                February 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-4" style="left: 900px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/reflections/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="img_7178" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/img_7178.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Reflections</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                May 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-5" style="left: 0px; top: 296px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/crops/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="p1090841" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/p1090841.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Crops</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                June 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-6" style="left: 300px; top: 296px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/shovels/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="shovels" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/shovels.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Shovels</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                July 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-7" style="left: 600px; top: 296px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/barns/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="barns" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/barns.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Barns</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                August 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
          <div class="three column post-8" style="left: 900px; top: 296px; position: absolute;">
            <a href="https://thurstoncdblog.wordpress.com/field/">
              <div class="featured-image">
                <img width="1024" height="768" class="attachment-photo" alt="p1090869" src="https://thurstoncdblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/p1090869.jpg?w=1024&amp;h=768&amp;crop=1" scale="0">
              </div>
              <!-- .featured-image -->

              <div>
                <h1 class="entry-title">Field</h1>
                <span class="entry-meta">
                                                                                                September 19, 2016
                                                                                        </span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .three -->
        </div>
        <!-- .row -->
      </div>
      <!-- .grid -->
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's what the visual issue(s) are in WordPress (after I have pasted in the HTML and CSS in their relevant places):

[Screenshot of issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thIjO.jpg)

I would be grateful for any advice, tips, or input the community has.

Thank you.

Comment: Some css in your wordpress site is causing this. Try changing the class name of the affected elements in your wordpress site to see if it's fixed ? Make sure that the classname is unique

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Still not having much luck. The only things I see as being affected is the .feature-image tag. Do you think it requires additional styling conditions?

Comment: Not sure. I would try to add `padding:0 !important; margin: 0 !important` to the elements with extra padding/margin to see if this fix the issue. Hard to debug without being able to inspect the website

Comment: Thank you for that, I think it's put me on the right track. Out of curiosity, I tried adding that to every single element with a padding or margin condition and what resulted fixed the lower right-hand image breaking from its div container--unfortunately the extreme spacing in-between titles and meta is still present, but it's a good start! (Oh and, I do realize my test was overkill. I'm now systematically removing that code addition until I find what caused the div breakage.

Comment: Good =) Glad to be able to help

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but now I'm at work again on the padding and height-width issue that's bloating the titles and meta. I think the issue is that the selectors native to the theme I'm using are overriding my code somehow. Do you know if there's a way to isolate only the code above and leave the prior css unaffected?

Comment: no good way to isolate the code. CSS is applied using class/id usually. Try to make sure that the elements has unique class/id and apply css accordingly. And learning to [inspect element](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnWL2d9bGPk) will help you tremendously

Comment: I finally narrowed down where the issue is, but now I'm having an issue separating it. When I inspected the meta and title area for a random picture, I determined that the code that was affecting the spacing was affecting all the headers in the entire document. Essentially it's the code that starts h1,h2,h3.......margin-top: 2.5em;
 margin-bottom: 2.5em;} By setting the margins to about .1em the issue for the gallery bloating is gone, but now that same edit affects all of the text css. Any tips given this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my issue. To summarize:

Thanks to Jacob Goh's help I figured out how to correct the images breaking their div containers using the line:

```
padding:0 !important; margin: 0 !important
```

in a few instances of my code.

The second issue was the padding around the title and meta-data under each image. Because I was applying my gallery to an existing WP template, editing the header margin data was messing with the entire site. That's "cascading" style sheets for ya. Anyways, after reading
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051687/how-to-target-headings-for-a-specific-div-id.), I realized what I needed to do, add a secondary complete set of header ids with a unique identifier (well...I say unique, all I did was use "header".

Here's what was available already in my code (this affected not only the header in my gallery code, but was affecting the whole website):

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol,
dl,
address,
form,
fieldset {
margin-top: 2.5em;
margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
```

And here's what I needed to add to the style sheet in addition (note the similarities):

```
#header h1,
#header h2,
#header h3,
#header h4,
#header h5,
#header h6,
#header p,
#header ul,
#header ol,
#header dl,
#header address,
#header form,
#header fieldset {
line-height: 1.05em;
margin-top: .1em;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

Also I should mention, I enclosed all of my HTML base code in the div identifier:

```
<div id="header">my code</div>
```

Anyways, that wrapped that up. And now to sleep!